# Shared Preferences used in OnReceive does not update

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that tracks battery information and stores it in Shared Preferences. Then from my main activity I have `BroadcastReceiver`(that has `OnReceive` for listening `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`)

Every time OnReceive occurs battery level and temperature changes, but my Shared Preferences leaves the same until I change my screen orientation(I think because of recreation of activity).
Please, help me to somehow make onReceive method also update shared preferences.

My Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    }
    ......

    /* Broadcast Receiver for battery stats  */
    BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        .....
        private TextView text;
        int level = -1;

        @Override   
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_text);
            text.setText("level"+level+"something from Shared Pref"+appPrefs.getAnything());
        }
    }
}
```

My Shared Preferences:

```
public class AppPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS_preferences"; //  Name of the file -.xml
         private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
         private Editor prefsEditor;

         public AppPreferences(Context context)
         {
             this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
             this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
         }

         public long getAnything() {
             return appSharedPrefs.getLong("Anything", 9);

         }

         public void setAnything(long a) {
             prefsEditor.putLong("Anything", a);
             prefsEditor.commit();
         }
```

My service:

```
BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ......
        appPrefs.setAnything(a);
```

So, why Shared Preferences are not updated as level or temperature in OnReceive method?
And what to do? Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Why are you putting a long into a boolean preference?

Comment: @draksia Because earlier I needed a long, I was calculating time in nano seconds, I could cast it to int, but will it solve my problem? :)

Comment: Why are you explictly instantiating an Activity? That's recipe for trouble from the start, even if the code did work.

Comment: @A--C what do you mean? It is not full code to save your time, only valuable information to make point of view

Comment: @whiteLT I am aware this code isn't complete. What I meant was that `appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());` shouldn't exist. Never treat an `Activity` as a normal class. Although you seem to have dodged a bullet by passing the Activity a context.

Comment: @A--C I am new to android so I did it by example from stackoverflow I think, I will then find a better way to use Shared Preferences. Do you have some thoughts on my problem?

Comment: It is really strange why during OnReceive sharedPref. data is not updated even it is changed. Of course if I restart program or change orientation of screen shared Prefs. are being updated

Comment: @whiteLT what intent does the service receiver listen for?

Comment: How are you sure its changed? I don't see any code that actually calls  setOnOrOFF

Comment: @A--C `IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);`

Comment: @dymmeh in service `appPrefs.setAnything(a);` and I know because it does change and represent correctly when orientation of screen is changed or program is restarted

Comment: @whiteLT I think your `setOnOrOff()` method declaration should be `setAnything()` no? Anyways, since both Receivers are listening for the same Intent, I'd say that the Activity's receiver is called first followed by the Service's. I would be inclined to only have one receiver in the service, which broadcasts a custom Intent to a custom receiver in the Activity.

Comment: Sorry, paste mistakes about `setOnOrOff()`, corrected. And about two receivers, I really need both (I think) because my Activity represents real time data. But maybe I can leave only one in service. But will it solve my problem about Shared Prefs. updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after so much research, I could make it work: just add this:

```
private Intent starterIntent;
```

in your class members area above class name, in my example below main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Intent starterIntent;
```

Then anywhere you want place a code to refresh activity without showing to user.:

```
                            finish();
                            starterIntent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(starterIntent);
                            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```